# pass a c++ vector or a map to an existing python script?

Tags: c++, python, boost

I have written a python script which displays a graph, i now need to pass it a vector or a map which is populated in a c++ program written by me. Is this possible? If so can anyone provide any examples please?

Comment: Are you considering something like swig? Or are you embedding a python interpreter into your c++?

Comment: i am open to any option as long as i can get it glued together, i am using matplotlib with python, so i will need to use a specific version that works with this library

Comment: i have just taken a look at swig, it could work, but can i use it to return a vectors from my C++ program which can then be interpreted by my python script?

Comment: You could use something like [this library](http://www.picklingtools.com/home). It allows you to pickle C++ vectors (you have to make them into `Arr`'s first)